# CUDA SDK examples throw various errors in multi-gpu system

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-12.04, multi-gpu

I have a Dell Precision Rack running Ubuntu Precise and featuring two Tesla C2075 plus a Quadro 600 which is the display device. I have recently finished some tests on my desktop-computer and now tried to port stuff to the workstation.

Since CUDA was not present I installed it according to [this guide](http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/installing-cuda-on-ubuntu-12-04/) and adapted the SDK Makefiles according to [this suggestions](http://laurencedawson.com/upgrading-to-cuda-4.0).

What I am now facing is that not a single sample (I did test like 10 different ones) is running. Those are the errors I am getting:

---

```
[deviceQuery] starting...

./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 10
-> invalid device ordinal
[deviceQuery] test results...
FAILED

> exiting in 3 seconds: 3...2...1...done!
```

---

```
[MonteCarloMultiGPU] starting...

CUDA error at MonteCarloMultiGPU.cpp:235 code=23510 (cudaErrorInvalidDevice) "cudaGetDeviceCount(&GPU_N)"MonteCarloMultiGPU
==================
Parallelization method  = threaded
Problem scaling         = weak
Number of GPUs          = 0
Total number of options = 0
Number of paths         = 262144
main(): generating input data...
main(): starting 0 host threads...
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

---

```
[reduction] starting...

reduction.cpp(124) : cudaSafeCallNoSync() Runtime API error 10 : invalid device ordinal.
```

---

```
[simplePrintf] starting...

simplePrintf.cu(193) : CUDA Runtime API error 10: invalid device ordinal.
```

---

As you can see most of the errors are pointing towards a problem with the cudaGetDeviceCount call which return error code 10. According to the manual the problem is:

```
cudaErrorInvalidDevice: This indicates that the device ordinal supplied by the user does not correspond to a valid CUDA device.
```

Unfortunately, the only solution I was able to find suggested to check the devices power plugs. I did that and there was nothing wrong with it. Restarting the workstation does not help either.

I'd be happy to supply more details on my configuration. Just leave a comment!

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOveflow. I would recommend checking whether you have `/dev/nvidia*` device files. If you don't, then read the instructions in the Linux getting starting guide regarding manually creating them.

Comment: @talonmies In my dev there are `nvidia0` and `nvidiactl`. How much files are there supposed to be?

Comment: There should be one per GPU, so three for your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the comments to my original question I was able to [find](http://troylee2008.blogspot.de/2012/05/cudagetdevicecount-returned-38.html) a solution. I followed  [this guide](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/rc.local) to learn how to set up the `rc.local` correctly (don't forget to `chmod` your script).